# login with requests library python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

i'm trying to click a log in button with requests library, is the first time that i use this library.  my code is:

```
import requests


def login(credentials):
    response = requests.post("https://www.kickz.com/en/checkout/login_offer", data=credentials)

if response.ok:
    print('success')
else:
    raise Exeption ('error', response.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials = {"E-Mail Address" : "help@me.com", "Password" : "please"}
    login(credentials)`
```

the code print 'success' but i have no idea how to click the log in button
the html code of the button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-green btn-lg"><span>Log in</span></button>
<span>Log in</span>
</button>
```

i've done it with Selenium, but i  would like to know if it's possibile done it with requests

thank you for dedicating your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to capture the curl request via the "inspect element" tool 
then convert it into python code with this tool 
https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: i'm trying to do it but noway... are you sure that i can click a button with request library?

Comment: "click a button" is just a request that you can simulate

Comment: how? could you help me? without using selenium library